# Infinite graph with degrees given

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal and suppose $$n, d: \kappa \to \big((\kappa+1)\setminus \{0\}\big) = \{1, \ldots, \kappa\}$$ are arbitrary functions.

Is there $E \subseteq \big\{\{x,y\}: x\neq y \in \kappa\big\}$ such that the graph $G=(\kappa,E)$ has the following property?

> > For all $k\in \kappa$ there are exactly $n(k)$ elements of $\kappa$ that have degree $d(k)$.

Comment: Is $\kappa$ countable? Title and anything else suggest that yes.

Comment: Oh sorry - have to change title!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find the following paper useful: [Degree sequences of infinite graphs, by Andreas Blass and Frank Harary](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/135582/jlms0010.pdf).

> The degree sequences of finite graphs, finite connected graphs, finite trees and finite forests have all
>   been characterized. Our present purpose is to provide such characterizations in the infinite case.

Comment: I can't view the article, so I gather you are saying that the answer is "No" to my question?

Comment: If my quick translation between your question and the notation from the paper is correct, the answer is in fact yes, and the graph can be taken to be a forest.